# Are there any web apps that can Convert PDF to word (or html) with good surport for tables?

Tags: webapp-rec, pdf

Is there a web app that will convert a PDF file to a word (or html) file including recovering tables?

(I wish to convert a PDF spec into a format I can use to drive system tests)

---

I have not accepted an answer yet, if someone wish to write an answer the compared the different options, I will accept it.

Comment: I would question whether this is a Web App.
Just open the Pdf in Word and the convert to what ever you want.

Comment: @Scott since when did word surport opening PDF files,  I know some versions of word can save to PDF after downloading a free add no.

Comment: @Scott don't forget that not everybody have Microsoft Word installed on their computers.. it's not free and if you are using Linux it's not even possible to install it.. :D

Comment: I would make the title more specific to match the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tested out [PDF to Word](http://www.pdftoword.com/) after a quick Google search, and it works perfectly. It'll let you convert an unlimited number of documents and send them to your email address.

Answer (score 8):

Try Google Docs.

Go to docs.google.com. In the top-left corner you'll see the button "Upload". Clicking that, you'll be presented with a page where you can select the file. Select the file, and be sure to click "**Convert text from PDF or image files to Google Docs documents.**"

Once you're in the subsequent uploaded document, you may have to clean it up a little. Converting a pdf to anything but an image can be a messy process.

Once you're ready, click File > Download as > Word (or HTML).

Comment: Are you sure you can actually do that? Because the only options that I have with my PDFs in Google Docs is to view and download them.

Comment: @Lipis I believe it's fairly new. It even does OCR on PDF image documents. The OCR isn't all that great though. Anyway, it's just below the Upload selector (in the Upload screen). It says `Select conversion options`

Answer (score 1):

You can try [OCR Terminal](http://www.ocrterminal.com) - its an online OCR service that'll convert PDF to Word. Their free account (email registration) gives away 20 free pages every month.  You can try emiling their support team to get PDF converted to HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Now there's a better tool: http://pdf2doc.com
It doesn't ask for email to deliver the results and has no silly limit on a file size.

Comment: Have you tested how well it works with tables.